# How do I select only a specific key's value from jsonb type in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a `jsonb` column which has data as below.

```
[
   {"key": "unit_type", "value": "Tablet", "display_name": "Unit Type"},
   {"key": "pack_type", "value": "Packet", "display_name": "Pack Type"},
   {"key": "units_in_pack", "value": "60", "display_name": "Units in Pack"},
   {"key": "item_unit", "value": "", "display_name": "Item unit"},
   {"key": "item_size", "value": "1", "display_name": "Item Size"}, 
   {"key": "details", "value": "", "display_name": "Details"},
   {"key": "slug", "value": "otc7087", "display_name": "Slug"}
]
```

I want to get the `value` field from the array which has a `key` called `slug`, so that when I do a select query over table, I get this particular value from the column. For the above row when I do `select name, slug, price from table`, I should get `med1, otc7087, 100` as the output. I am unable to build a query for this thing. I can get all the keys or all the values but how do I select a particular one in the same select query?

Or simply how do I select just the `slugs` from the table? That will answer.

Comment: This is a weird way to store data. It's like you're doing EAV with json. Why don't you store objects? `{"unit_type": {"value": "Tablet", "display_name": "Unit Type"}, ...}` or something?

Comment: Also, where does `med1` and `100` come from? Some data not shown here?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention. These are some other columns. I want just the `slug` from the above column and these two or others will be in select statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i believe your json is much more structured , 
just try jsonb_to_recordset

for ex:

```
select * from json_to_recordset('[
   {"key": "unit_type", "value": "Tablet", "display_name": "Unit Type"},
   {"key": "pack_type", "value": "Packet", "display_name": "Pack Type"},
   {"key": "units_in_pack", "value": "60", "display_name": "Units in Pack"},
   {"key": "item_unit", "value": "", "display_name": "Item unit"},
   {"key": "item_size", "value": "1", "display_name": "Item Size"}, 
   {"key": "details", "value": "", "display_name": "Details"},
   {"key": "slug", "value": "otc7087", "display_name": "Slug"}
]') as x(key int, value text, display_name text);
```

it will convert jsonb into table with key, value, display_name as columns and then you can fire any type query over it, it works for extracting keys also, whereas the way @Craig Ringer suggested you won't be able to convert it into table like things and firing complex select query like not in , != , range queries , ilike will be really difficult and might be less performant.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to search all elements of a json array for an object with a particular value for a given key, then return the value of another key if matched.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
WITH my_table(jsonblob) AS (VALUES('[
   {"key": "unit_type", "value": "Tablet", "display_name": "Unit Type"},
   {"key": "pack_type", "value": "Packet", "display_name": "Pack Type"},
   {"key": "units_in_pack", "value": "60", "display_name": "Units in Pack"},
   {"key": "item_unit", "value": "", "display_name": "Item unit"},
   {"key": "item_size", "value": "1", "display_name": "Item Size"}, 
   {"key": "details", "value": "", "display_name": "Details"},
   {"key": "slug", "value": "otc7087", "display_name": "Slug"}
]'::jsonb))
SELECT elem ->> 'value'
FROM my_table
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(jsonblob) elem
WHERE (elem ->> 'key') = 'slug';
```

i.e. select from the table, unpack the array into a join, filter the join table for the desired object by looking for the json key `key` with value `slug`, and return the value of the json key `value` in the `select` clause when found.

If you want multiple different values from the same json object you need multiple joins, one per desired value.

This is a pretty ugly way to store variable key/value format data. I'd suggest storage like:

```
{"unit_type": {"value": "Tablet", "display_name": "Unit Type"}, ...}
```

where you can actually look up the keys.